# How to solve NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I have project's urls.py file whiche located at `forecast/urls` inside it i am trying to setup url routing for my app's urls

```
from django.contrib import admin                             
from django.urls import path,include                       
from django.contrib.auth import login                         
       urlpatterns = [
            path('auth/',include
                     ('authorization.urls')),
            ]
```

In `authorization/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path                               
from . import views                                        
        urlpatterns = [
             path('login/',
             views.login_name), 
         ]
```

After running server i want to open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/` and i got

```
NoReverseMatch at/   
auth/login/
 Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is 
 not a valid view function or pattern    
 name.
```

Based on my urls setup i expect that path function from project's urls.py will give to included authorization/urls.py path `auth/` than second path from `authorization/urls.py` will add to it pattern `login` than constructed `auth/login/` will give to my view function if i am right why i got NoReverse error. Can anyone guide me what i am doing wrong

My full traceback is here

```
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/Django Version:2.2.4Exception Type:NoReverseMatchException Value:Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.Exception Location:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668Python Executable:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/bin/pythonPython Version:3.7.4Python Path:['/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast', '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast', '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python37.zip', '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7', '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7', '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']Server time:Mon, 30 Dec 2019 06:58:18 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the url a name so that you can use it when you want to reverse it

```
path('login/', views.login_name, name='login'),
```

Comment: Than what url i should open to access auth/login/ page ?